# Asking about a union of languages and how they interact

Tags: computer-science, computational-mathematics, computer-arithmetic

if we take a language, $L= \{b^{2n}a^n \mid n \gt 0\} \cup \{b^{3n}a^n \mid n \gt 0\}$

would this be the same as $L=\{b^{2n}a^n b^{3n} a^n \mid n \gt 0\}$ ?

Comment: See my edits to the question for proper MathJax usage.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. Does the word $b^2ab^3a$ belongs to your language?